# java out of memory after wildfly startup

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, wildfly

after starting wildfly and deploying some wars on it, I am getting following error. Please help me and do not mark it as duplicate because i already have searched a lot and have tried different solution.

```
    #
    # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1431312 bytes for Chunk::new
    # Possible reasons:
    #   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
    #   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
    # Possible solutions:
    #   Reduce memory load on the system
    #   Increase physical memory or swap space
    #   Check if swap backing store is full
    #   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
    #   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
    #   Decrease number of Java threads
    #
    #  Out of Memory Error, pid=3896
    #
    ]
      0x0000000048fd5800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|7a85c3ae]-HelperThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2692, stack(0x000000005ff40000,0x0000000060040000)]
      0x0000000048fd8800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|7a85c3ae]-HelperThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4344, stack(0x000000005fe40000,0x000000005ff40000)]
      0x0000000048fd7800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|7a85c3ae]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4868, stack(0x000000005fd40000,0x000000005fe40000)]

      0x0000000048fce800 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 219" [_thread_blocked, id=3772, stack(0x000000005f140000,0x000000005f240000)]
      0x0000000048e45800 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 163" [_thread_blocked, id=1344, stack(0x0000000058a20000,0x0000000058b20000)]
      0x0000000048e35000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 141" [_thread_blocked, id=4652, stack(0x0000000057420000,0x0000000057520000)]
      0x0000000048e34000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 140" [_thread_blocked, id=5096, stack(0x0000000057320000,0x0000000057420000)]

      0x00000000391a3000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 122" [_thread_blocked, id=4684, stack(0x0000000056120000,0x0000000056220000)]
      0x0000000043dde800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6a03136npih|4795e3d8]-HelperThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3692, stack(0x0000000055e60000,0x0000000055f60000)]
      0x0000000044494800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6a03136npih|4795e3d8]-HelperThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5720, stack(0x0000000055340000,0x0000000055440000)]
      0x000000004448c800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6a03136npih|4795e3d8]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4636, stack(0x0000000054c10000,0x0000000054d10000)]
      0x0000000044495000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6a03136npih|4795e3d8]-AdminTaskTimer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=488, stack(0x0000000055440000,0x0000000055540000)]
      0x0000000044492000 JavaThread "Thread-18 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=cabe2dae-e6ad-11e5-9468-e7da2145920f-328130029)" [_thread_blocked, id=4596, stack(0x0000000055570000,0x0000000055670000)]
      0x0000000044490800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|69ac024b]-HelperThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5756, stack(0x0000000055070000,0x0000000055170000)]
      0x0000000044493800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|69ac024b]-HelperThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2536, stack(0x0000000054f70000,0x0000000055070000)]
      0x0000000044493000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|69ac024b]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4252, stack(0x0000000054910000,0x0000000054a10000)]
      0x000000004448f000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|69ac024b]-AdminTaskTimer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2716, stack(0x0000000054810000,0x0000000054910000)]
      0x0000000044491800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6928by91kh|15356c76]-HelperThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5584, stack(0x0000000052c80000,0x0000000052d80000)]
      0x000000004448e800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6928by91kh|15356c76]-HelperThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5204, stack(0x00000000528d0000,0x00000000529d0000)]
      0x000000004448d800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6928by91kh|15356c76]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4848, stack(0x0000000052250000,0x0000000052350000)]
      0x000000004448a800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd6928by91kh|15356c76]-AdminTaskTimer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5384, stack(0x0000000051ea0000,0x0000000051fa0000)]
      0x0000000044489800 JavaThread "Thread-17 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=cabe2dae-e6ad-11e5-9468-e7da2145920f-328130029)" [_thread_blocked, id=3372, stack(0x0000000052030000,0x0000000052130000)]
      0x0000000044486800 JavaThread "Store myEntityCacheRegionName Expiry Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2908, stack(0x00000000527d0000,0x00000000528d0000)]
      0x0000000044489000 JavaThread "Store myEntityCacheRegionName Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1464, stack(0x00000000526d0000,0x00000000527d0000)]
      0x0000000044487800 JavaThread "Store org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2768, stack(0x0000000052150000,0x0000000052250000)]
      0x0000000044485000 JavaThread "Store org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache Spool Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3144, stack(0x0000000051710000,0x0000000051810000)]
      0x0000000044486000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|7a85c3ae]-HelperThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4112, stack(0x0000000051ba0000,0x0000000051ca0000)]
      0x0000000044483000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|7a85c3ae]-HelperThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4804, stack(0x0000000051aa0000,0x0000000051ba0000)]
      0x0000000044482000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|7a85c3ae]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3320, stack(0x00000000519a0000,0x0000000051aa0000)]
      0x0000000044481800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|7a85c3ae]-AdminTaskTimer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=572, stack(0x00000000518a0000,0x00000000519a0000)]
      0x0000000044480800 JavaThread "Thread-16 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=cabe2dae-e6ad-11e5-9468-e7da2145920f-328130029)" [_thread_blocked, id=2600, stack(0x0000000050c10000,0x0000000050d10000)]
      0x000000004447d800 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 121" [_thread_blocked, id=5464, stack(0x0000000050070000,0x0000000050170000)]
      0x000000004447f000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 120" [_thread_blocked, id=4528, stack(0x000000004ff70000,0x0000000050070000)]
      0x000000004447d000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 119" [_thread_blocked, id=5060, stack(0x000000004fe70000,0x000000004ff70000)]
      0x000000004447e800 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 118" [_thread_blocked, id=4392, stack(0x000000004fd70000,0x000000004fe70000)]
      0x0000000044479000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 117" [_thread_blocked, id=4348, stack(0x000000004fc70000,0x000000004fd70000)]
      0x000000004447c000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 116" [_thread_blocked, id=204, stack(0x000000004fb70000,0x000000004fc70000)]
      0x000000004447a000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 115" [_thread_blocked, id=4788, stack(0x000000004fa70000,0x000000004fb70000)]
      0x0000000044478800 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 114" [_thread_blocked, id=1952, stack(0x000000004f970000,0x000000004fa70000)]
      0x000000004447a800 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 113" [_thread_blocked, id=3868, stack(0x000000004f870000,0x000000004f970000)]
      0x000000004447b800 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 112" [_thread_blocked, id=1956, stack(0x000000004f770000,0x000000004f870000)]
      0,0x000000004d100000)]
      0x0000000043ddf000 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4436, stack(0x000000004cb20000,0x000000004cc20000)]
      0x0000000043de0000 JavaThread "Thread-14 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=cabe2dae-e6ad-11e5-9468-e7da2145920f-328130029)" [_thread_blocked, id=5512, stack(0x000000004ba50000,0x000000004bb50000)]
      0x0000000043ddc000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|491be0f8]-HelperThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=948, stack(0x000000004b750000,0x000000004b850000)]
      0x0000000043dda000 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|491be0f8]-HelperThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3584, stack(0x000000004b650000,0x000000004b750000)]
      0x0000000043ddb800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|491be0f8]-HelperThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2728, stack(0x000000004b550000,0x000000004b650000)]
      0x0000000043dd7800 JavaThread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqtcf29mzd64m27yhr52|491be0f8]-AdminTaskTimer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3888, stack(0x000000004b450000,0x000000004b550000)]
      0x0000000043dd5800 JavaThread "Thread-4 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-78403865)" [_thread_blocked, id=3640, stack(0x000000004ae00000,0x000000004af00000)]
      0x0000000043dd6000 JavaThread "Thread-13 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=cabe2dae-e6ad-11e5-9468-e7da2145920f-328130029)" [_thread_blocked, id=6028, stack(0x000000004af50000,0x000000004b050000)]
      0x0000000044410800 JavaThread "Thread-3 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-78403865)" [_thread_blocked, id=3576, stack(0x000000004ab00000,0x000000004ac00000)]
      0x0000000044410000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 85" [_thread_blocked, id=5048, stack(0x000000004aa00000,0x000000004ab00000)]
      0x000000004440a000 JavaThread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 74" [_thread_blocked, id=4272, stack(0x0000000049f00000,0x000000004a000000)]
      0x000000004440a800 JavaThread "Thread-1 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-957947347)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4828, stack(0x0000000049e00000,0x0000000049f00000)]
      0x0000000044409000 JavaThread "Thread-12 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=cabe2dae-e6ad-11e5-9468-e7da2145920f-328130029)" [_thread_blocked, id=5568, stack(0x0000000049d00000,0x0000000049e00000)]


    Other Threads:
      0x0000000035107000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000036190000,0x0000000036290000] [id=3616]
      0x00000000369ba800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000036e90000,0x0000000036f90000] [id=6124]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap:
     PSYoungGen      total 1808896K, used 1414723K [0x0000000715580000, 0x00000007bba00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
      eden space 1513472K, 93% used [0x0000000715580000,0x000000076bb10e68,0x0000000771b80000)
      from space 295424K, 0% used [0x0000000790f00000,0x0000000790f00000,0x00000007a2f80000)
      to   space 511488K, 0% used [0x0000000771b80000,0x0000000771b80000,0x0000000790f00000)
     ParOldGen       total 937984K, used 833739K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005f9400000, 0x0000000715580000)
      object space 937984K, 88% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000005f2e32f40,0x00000005f9400000)
     Metaspace       used 209642K, capacity 218962K, committed 219328K, reserved 1239040K
      class space    used 26099K, capacity 28842K, committed 28928K, reserved 1048576K

    Card table byte_map: [0x00000000218e0000,0x00000000228f0000] byte_map_base: 0x000000001eae0000

    Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005a9f4040
     Begin Bits: [0x00000000237a0000, 0x000000002b7a0000)
     End Bits:   [0x000000002b7a0000, 0x00000000337a0000)

    Polling page: 0x00000000009a0000

    CodeCache: size=524288Kb used=44104Kb max_used=45659Kb free=480183Kb
     bounds [0x00000000010e0000, 0x0000000003dc0000, 0x00000000210e0000]
     total_blobs=13716 nmethods=12938 adapters=688
     compilation: enabled

    Compilation events (10 events):
    Event: 39.600 Thread 0x0000000035147800 16071       3       io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache::<init> (54 bytes)
    Event: 39.600 Thread 0x0000000035147800 nmethod 16071 0x000000000151ac10 code [0x000000000151adc0, 0x000000000151b3e8]
    Event: 39.617 Thread 0x0000000035147800 16073       1       io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelConfig::getAllocator (5 bytes)
    Event: 39.617 Thread 0x0000000035147800 nmethod 16073 0x0000000003893250 code [0x00000000038933a0, 0x00000000038934b0]
    Event: 39.618 Thread 0x0000000035147800 16074       3       io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache::powerOfTwo (47 bytes)
    Event: 39.618 Thread 0x0000000035147800 nmethod 16074 0x00000000038c1110 code [0x00000000038c1260, 0x00000000038c1410]
    Event: 39.618 Thread 0x0000000035147800 16075       3       io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$SubPageMemoryRegionCache::<init> (6 bytes)
    Event: 39.618 Thread 0x0000000035147800 nmethod 16075 0x0000000003a9a2d0 code [0x0000000003a9a440, 0x0000000003a9a5c8]
    Event: 39.620 Thread 0x0000000035147800 16076       3       io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf::writeByte (28 bytes)
    Event: 39.620 Thread 0x0000000035147800 nmethod 16076 0x0000000002fa1690 code [0x0000000002fa1840, 0x0000000002fa1dd8]

    GC Heap History (10 events):
    Event: 23.021 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=25 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 1154048K, used 1028096K [0x0000000715580000, 0x0000000779980000, 0x00000007c0000000)
      eden space 1028096K, 100% used [0x0000000715580000,0x0000000754180000,0x0000000754180000)
      from space 125952K, 0% used [0x0000000754180000,0x0000000754180000,0x000000075bc80000)
      to   space 143360K, 0% used [0x0000000770d80000,0x0000000770d80000,0x0000000779980000)
     ParOldGen       total 497152K, used 209939K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005de580000, 0x0000000715580000)
      object space 497152K, 42% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000005ccd04d50,0x00000005de580000)
     Metaspace       used 125479K, capacity 133446K, committed 133696K, reserved 1165312K
      class space    used 16107K, capacity 18489K, committed 18560K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 23.168 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=25 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 1480192K, used 129780K [0x0000000715580000, 0x000000077b180000, 0x00000007c0000000)
      eden space 1336832K, 0% used [0x0000000715580000,0x0000000715580000,0x0000000766f00000)
      from space 143360K, 90% used [0x0000000770d80000,0x0000000778c3d010,0x0000000779980000)
      to   space 162304K, 0% used [0x0000000766f00000,0x0000000766f00000,0x0000000770d80000)
     ParOldGen       total 497152K, used 209963K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005de580000, 0x0000000715580000)
      object space 497152K, 42% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000005ccd0ad60,0x00000005de580000)
     Metaspace       used 125479K, capacity 133446K, committed 133696K, reserved 1165312K
      class space    used 16107K, capacity 18489K, committed 18560K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 28.647 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=26 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 1480192K, used 1466612K [0x0000000715580000, 0x000000077b180000, 0x00000007c0000000)
      eden space 1336832K, 100% used [0x0000000715580000,0x0000000766f00000,0x0000000766f00000)
      from space 143360K, 90% used [0x0000000770d80000,0x0000000778c3d010,0x0000000779980000)
      to   space 162304K, 0% used [0x0000000766f00000,0x0000000766f00000,0x0000000770d80000)
     ParOldGen       total 497152K, used 209963K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005de580000, 0x0000000715580000)
      object space 497152K, 42% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000005ccd0ad60,0x00000005de580000)
     Metaspace       used 173144K, capacity 182010K, committed 182336K, reserved 1206272K
      class space    used 21978K, capacity 24610K, committed 24704K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 28.997 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=26 (full 5):
     PSYoungGen      total 1499136K, used 162299K [0x0000000715580000, 0x00000007a2f80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
      eden space 1336832K, 0% used [0x0000000715580000,0x0000000715580000,0x0000000766f00000)
      from space 162304K, 99% used [0x0000000766f00000,0x0000000770d7ee80,0x0000000770d80000)
      to   space 295424K, 0% used [0x0000000790f00000,0x0000000790f00000,0x00000007a2f80000)
     ParOldGen       total 497152K, used 497067K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005de580000, 0x0000000715580000)
      object space 497152K, 99% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000005de56adc0,0x00000005de580000)
     Metaspace       used 173144K, capacity 182010K, committed 182336K, reserved 1206272K
      class space    used 21978K, capacity 24610K, committed 24704K, reserved 1048576K
    }

    Deoptimization events (10 events):
    Event: 38.873 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000001367660 method=sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(Lsun/util/calendar/CalendarDate;J)V @ 74
    Event: 39.081 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002716d68 method=java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(Ljava/util/Map;Z)V @ 15
    Event: 39.247 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000015796d8 method=java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)I @ 1
    Event: 39.248 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000001587e38 method=java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)I @ 1
    Event: 39.255 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000001f18d74 method=java.lang.Class.searchMethods([Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; @ 47
    Event: 39.257 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000001d1a37c method=java.lang.Class.searchMethods([Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; @ 47
    Event: 39.257 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000023dd434 method=java.lang.Class.searchMethods([Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; @ 47
    Event: 39.309 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000020fafec method=java.util.TreeSet.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 13
    Event: 39.570 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000029aae58 method=java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken()Ljava/lang/String; @ 12
    Event: 39.601 Thread 0x0000000044488000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001317258 method=java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;[BII)[C @ 1

    Internal exceptions (10 events):
    Event: 39.468 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/IdentityTokenResolvableBeanInfo> (0x000000076a5ab060) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line
    Event: 39.468 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/AbstractIdentityTokenizedBeanInfo> (0x000000076a5ae580) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, li§$Óææ»C@
    Event: 39.468 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/AbstractIdentityTokenizedCustomizer> (0x000000076a5b1b08) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, í À ì»C@
    Event: 39.468 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/IdentityTokenResolvableCustomizer> (0x000000076a5b6090) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, ližü‹ ñ»C@
    Event: 39.468 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/PoolBackedDataSourceBaseCustomizer> (0x000000076a5ba2b0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, l­ þ2þ»C@
    Event: 39.469 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/AbstractPoolBackedDataSourceCustomizer> (0x000000076a5d97b0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpù
    Event: 39.469 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/AbstractComboPooledDataSourceCustomizer> (0x000000076a62cf30) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, lá‚lc$¼C@
    Event: 39.470 Thread 0x0000000048fc4000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSourceCustomizer> (0x000000076a69e750) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]7´s~éÌC@
    Event: 39.601 Thread 0x000000005c781000 Exception <a 'java/lang/OutOfMemoryError'> (0x000000076b1e2080) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\unsafe.cpp, line 602]
    Event: 39.615 Thread 0x0000000044408800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076b031ae8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\2855\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1280]

    Events (10 events):
    Event: 39.603 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
    Event: 39.617 Thread 0x0000000048fc5800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x000000000203ff94 sp=0x000000005e07ee50
    Event: 39.617 Thread 0x0000000048fc5800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000112787f sp=0x000000005e07ec40 mode 0
    Event: 39.619 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 39.619 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
    Event: 39.621 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 39.621 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
    Event: 39.624 Thread 0x000000005c782800 Thread added: 0x000000005c782800
    Event: 39.626 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 39.627 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done


    Dynamic libraries:
    0x00007ff7ecbd0000 - 0x00007ff7ecc07000     C:\myapp\Programs\java\bin\java.exe
    0x00007ff83e2d0000 - 0x00007ff83e47d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    0x00007ff83dfe0000 - 0x00007ff83e11e000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
    0x00007ff83b650000 - 0x00007ff83b765000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
    0x00007ff839b90000 - 0x00007ff839c1e000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
    0x00007ff827b60000 - 0x00007ff827bb3000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL

    0x00007ff83da40000 - 0x00007ff83da49000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
    0x00007ff83b570000 - 0x00007ff83b5bf000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
    0x00007ff83a2a0000 - 0x00007ff83a2c8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll

    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -Xms256m -Xmx8192m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\myapp\Logs\myapp.WildFly\boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:../standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.server.log.dir=C:\myapp\Logs\myapp.WildFly -Djboss.server.temp.dir=C:\myapp\Temp\myapp.WildFly\temp -Djboss.server.data.dir=C:\myapp\Temp\myapp.WildFly\data -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=false -Dignore.bind.address=true -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.unsecure=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.jgroups=MN4DCPPENVW001 -Djgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts=0.0.0.0[7600] -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Duser.language=en -Djava.library.path=./lib -Dwrapper.key=bkhW8z04IFRZVDU9HST-Dd1-2H83VHAT -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=4712 -Dwrapper.version=3.5.23-st -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.arch=x86 -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=5 -Dwrapper.lang.domain=wrapper -Dwrapper.lang.folder=../lang 
    java_command: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.jboss.modules.Main -mp ../modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=../ -P=../standalone/configuration/myapp.properties
    java_class_path (initial): ./wrapper.jar;../jboss-modules.jar
    Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

    Environment Variables:
    PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;
    USERNAME=MN4DCPPENVW001$
    OS=Windows_NT
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 , 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.17415)

    CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

    Memory: 4k page, physical 16776692k(9630136k free), swap 16776692k(844k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_40-b25), built on Feb 10 2015 21:53:57 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

    time: Mon Feb 27 06:05:50 2017
    elapsed time: 41 seconds (0d 0h 0m 41s)
```

Comment: why don't you post the arguments used to launch the jvm?

Comment: You probably have a memory leak in your code. Are you returning your connections to the pool? Are you sure?

Comment: It is not clear if the OofM happens after some use, after deploying, more details are needed

Comment: @efekctive PFB jvm arguments:wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Xms1024m
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Xmx8192m
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: Are you using JDK 8?  There's no perm gen anymore.  How did you configure your meta space?

Comment: I found them in the post. There is also a message that the 32 bit limit was hit.

Comment: @efekctive after deployment it immediately goes out of memory

Comment: one more ineteresting point about it is if i am setting this parameter wrapper.java.additional.4=-Xmx8192m from 8192m to 6000m or less then my application is working fine, but if i already have a lot of free RAM then why should i reduce it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, i am sure all connections are returned to pool and as i have mentioned in my comment that this issue resolves by reducing max size, so I dont think its an issue related to connection pool memory leak. But it will be good if you suggest me in detail. I will follow it.

Comment: This regard the 32 bit comment, it states that is one of the possible causes. Have you tried to profile it?

Comment: I dont have a lot of information about profile, can you share some more information about it.

Comment: just use visualjvm or something like that, it will give you a picture of where the memory is going. If this is a bug then you have the hard data already

Comment: 1.8.0_40 is a bit old at this point. Is it reproducible in [1.8.0_121](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of memory because you have installed the 32 bit (Windows x86) version of the JDK installed by something like jdk-8u121-windows-i586.exe.

You need to install the 64 bit (Windows x64) version which will have an installer named something like jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe.

The `8u121` is the JDK version and will change over time.

Comment: No Steve, Its not the case. I am using 64- bit version only. I had checked it as it was already shown in possible solutions in logs.